# PowerShell XML Multiple ChildNodes Comma Separated Strings to Array

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell

I have an API for a Sonus SBC that returns results in XML for analogue ports. I have three child nodes with the same number of values in each that I need to turn into an array/table. The problem is each node has a comma delimited string so I am left with three objects each containing a string like below:

```
ApplyToChannelList      1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4
ChannelOwnNumberList    71750,51375,53004,53146
FXSHotlineNumberList    53940,,,70309
```

I have tried trying to `ConvertFrom-String` but that creates three separate arrays that I can't work out how to join together.
I have tried a `For-Each` that would not process anything and gave no result.

- I have tried splitting the strings and adding them to a custom object.
- I have tried splitting the strings and joining them together with commas to try and make an array.

My guess is I need to split the strings first and then get them into a custom object using possibly nested `For-Each` but when my first `For-Each` fails it makes it tricky.

To get the three nodes I need I am using the following:

```
$rest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BackupUrl -Method GET -ContentType "text/html;charset=UTF-8" -Body $null -WebSession $ps -Verbose
$xml = ([xml]$rest.Trim())
$child = $xml.ChildNodes.Cassg | Select-Object ApplyToChannelList, ChannelOwnNumberList, FXSHotlineNumberList
```

Any suggestions or tips on what to type of commands to try is greatly appreciated.

#### Expected Output:

```
ApplyToChannelList ChannelOwnNumberList FXSHotlineNumberList
1.1                 71750               
1.2                 51375               56072
```

#### XML Output

```
id                              : 20001
href                            : https://hostname.dns/rest/cassg/20001
ActionSetTableId                : 0
ApplyToChannelList              : 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,2.10,2.11,2.12,2.13,2.14,2.15,2.16,2.17,2.18,2.19,2.20
CallForward                     : 0
CallForwardActivate             : *72
CallForwardDeactivate           : *73
CallInformationFormatENM        : 0
CallerIDType                    : 0
CallerIdPrivacySignaling        : 
CasEnMProfileId                 : 0
CasLineType                     : 0
CasLoopStartFxoProfileId        : 0
CasLoopStartFxsProfileId        : CasLoopStartFxsProfileId
CasR2ProfileId                  : 0
CasSgDTMFCallerIDEndDelimiter   : 12
CasSgDTMFCallerIDStartDelimiter : 13
CasSgDirection                  : 2
CasSgENMDelimiterDigit          : 15
CasSgENMEndDigit                : 15
CasSgENMStartDigit              : 15
CasSgHuntMethod                 : 5
CasSgRingbackPlayPolicy         : 0
CasSignalingType                : 0
CasSupplementaryProfileId       : 0
ChannelOwnNumberList            : 71750,51375,53004,53146,53940,58940,70153,70309,71125,71681,75033,75021,75027,75015,75104,75120,75126,75145,75151,75320,75326,75351,75380,75449,52417,52895,75393,58627,53154,58473,51932,51871,53022,53595,19144,19152,19127,1
                                  9137,19101,19105,19112,19117,53410,54952
ConfigIEState                   : 1
Description                     : CAS FXS Analog Ports
EndOfDialDigit                  : 
FXSCallForwardingNumberList     : ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
FXSHotlineNumberList            : ,,,,,,,,,,56072,56072,56072,56072,56072,,,,56072,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
NoChannelAvailableId            : 34
RelayCallingName                : 1
RouteTableId                    : RouteTableId
TimerSanitySetup                : 255000
ToneTableId                     : ToneTableId
customAdminState                : 1
rt_CasSgCurrentCalls            : 1
rt_CasSgIncomingCallsAttempted  : 197
rt_CasSgIncomingCallsConnected  : 143
rt_CasSgOutgoingCallsAttempted  : 22
rt_CasSgOutgoingCallsConnected  : 9
rt_CasSignalingType             : 0
```

Comment: Please, share with us an example representation of the XML as well as the expected output.

Comment: Thanks Santiago. I am not sure how to paste the XML output properly. I am about to go into a meeting but will come back and try and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this, you would need to use `$xml.ChildNodes.Cassg` instead of `$test` in my case.

I'm not sure if you actually want to remove the leading commas from `FXSHotlineNumberList`, but in case you do, use this:

```sh
$fxsNumber = $test.FXSHotlineNumberList.TrimStart(',').Split(',')
```

```sh
# Since I don't have the original XML I'm using this to reproduce the object you already have.
$test = [pscustomobject]@{
    ApplyToChannelList = '1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,2.10,2.11,2.12,2.13,2.14,2.15,2.16,2.17,2.18,2.19,2.20'
    ChannelOwnNumberList = '71750,51375,53004,53146,53940,58940,70153,70309,71125,71681,75033,75021,75027,75015,75104,75120,75126,75145,75151,75320,75326,75351,75380,75449,52417,52895,75393,58627,53154,58473,51932,51871,53022,53595,19144,19152,19127,19137,19101,19105,19112,19117,53410,54952'
    FXSHotlineNumberList = ',,,,,,,,,,56072,56072,56072,56072,56072,,,,56072,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
}

$chnlist = $test.ApplyToChannelList.Split(',')
$chnOwnNumber = $test.ChannelOwnNumberList.Split(',')
$fxsNumber = $test.FXSHotlineNumberList.Split(',')

$count = ($chnlist.Count,$chnOwnNumber.Count,$fxsNumber.Count | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

$result = for($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ApplyToChannelList = $chnlist[$i]
        ChannelOwnNumberList = $chnOwnNumber[$i]
        FXSHotlineNumberList = $fxsNumber[$i]
    }
}
```

#### Output

```sh
PS /> $result | Select-Object -First 20

ApplyToChannelList ChannelOwnNumberList FXSHotlineNumberList
------------------ -------------------- --------------------
1.1                71750                                    
1.2                51375                                    
1.3                53004                                    
1.4                53146                                    
1.5                53940                                    
1.6                58940                                    
1.7                70153                                    
1.8                70309                                    
1.9                71125                                    
1.10               71681                                    
1.11               75033                56072               
1.12               75021                56072               
1.13               75027                56072               
1.14               75015                56072               
1.15               75104                56072               
1.16               75120                                    
1.17               75126                                    
1.18               75145                                    
1.19               75151                56072               
1.20               75320
```

Comment: Thank you so much Santiago. 
That is doing exactly what I was trying to. If you don't mind answering a quick question, I have seen variations of what you have provided with the count/measure object and $i = 0 and it has confused the hello out of me what is actually going on.
I assume the $count part is working out which column has the most entries so it makes that the first but I don't have the foggiest idea what is going on in the for brackets for the result. Or am I totally off base?
Thanks again.

Comment: @Thurmus since you're merging 3 arrays `$chnlist`, `$chnOwnNumber` and `$fxsNumber`, you need to be sure which one has the most number of elements, one way of quickly and easy finding that out is using [`measure-object -Maximum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: @Thurmus The `for loop` is just a loop from 0 to `$count` and on each iteration you're creating a `pscustomobject` with 3 elements that correspond to the position of the 3 arrays you're merging. You would need to read about this, it's not something I can easily explain. If the answer was helpful and solved your problem please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it may help others in the future.

Comment: @Thurmus happy to help!